# Python - Turning a list of dictionaries into a dictionary with lists

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm having difficulty with aggregating data within Python.
I wrote a program that extracts data from an Oracle DB and converts it into a list with dictionaries. Each dictionary contains the DB column names as keys

Looking something like this:

```
[{ColumnName1 : Value, Columnname2 : Value}, 
{ColumnName1 : Value, Columnname2 : Value}]
```

The problem I'm having is the redundant columnnames. From this list of dictionaries I would like to create a dictionary containing each column name as a key only once. After that adding a list of the values that belong to that columnname.

Any Ideas?

I'm using Cx_Oracle to extract the data from the DB.
I'm using the following code to create the list of dictionaries. 
The reason I'm doing this is because Oracle_CX doesn't return column names, and I really need those.

The code to build the list of dictionaries:

```
def rows_to_dict_list(cursor):
   columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
   return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor]
```

Comment: What is your desired structure of the data? Please edit the question to give example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
def rows_to_dict_list(cursor):
   columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
   return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor]
```

Try:

```
def rows_to_dict_list(cursor):
    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    out = {i[0]: [] for i in cursor.description}
    for row in cursor:
        for key, value in zip(columns, row):
            out[key].append(value)
return out
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked!. I have to admit I don't fully understand what you did. Could you explain it?

Comment: So in your code you are first creating a list of column names (the `columns` variable), then you return a list of dictionaries of rows ( dictionary of the zip of columns and row data).


In my code, instead we create a dictionary of column names, with empty lists as the values, then iterate through the dataset, first by row, then by key-value pair (created by zipping columns and row, as in your code).  For each key value pair, we add the value to the key's list in the output dictionary, resulting in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

The previous way of storring your data was indeed not optimal due to the repetition of keys. Try this:

```
old = [{ColumnName1 : Value11, Columnname2 : Value21, ...}, {ColumnName1 : Value12, Columnname2 : Value22, ...}, ...]
new_dict = {}
for subdict in a:
    for k, v in subdict.items():
        new_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)  # thanks to @volcano
print(new_dict)  # {ColumnName1: [value11, value12, ...], ColumnName1: [value12, value22, ...], ...}
```

---

But to be honest, the best way would be not to build the list of dictionaries in the first place and to go for a dictionary of lists directly. Now to do that effectively one would have to know a bit more about the structure of your DB + I believe that you can do it on your own. Just correlate the indexes of the returned by the query tuples to the column names and you are done.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Iterating over the values in my dictionaries is impossible.The values are often floats, integers, dates.

Comment: Oops, typo. Sorry. You do not have to iterate over the values.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, you don't really need assignment - one line *new_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)* will do

Answer (score 0):

Don't make that list of dictionaries in the first place; build up the dictionary.

```
def rows_to_lists_dict(cursor):
   column_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
   columns = {name: [] for name in column_names}
   for row in cursor:
       for name, column in zip(column_names, row):
           columns[name].append(column)
   return columns
```